# Perforce "p4 sync" not working properly

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

Totally confused with the strange behavior of "p4 sync". Tried running the following commands

Note: The filename is not present in workspace

> p4 sync //depot/filename
>   --- shows that files are up-to-date
>
> p4 have //depot/filename
>   --- shows files not on client

Thought may be the perforce server thinks the file is present in its client's have database. So deleted the file using

> p4 sync //depot/filename#none
>   --- shows files up-to-date
>
> p4 sync //depot/filename#head
>   --- shows files up-to-date

Finally when I say

> p4 have //depot/filename
>   --- shows files not on client

Then I did

> p4 sync -f //depot/filename#head
>   --- shows //depot/filename - deleted as c:/workspace/filename

and in the end

> p4 have //depot/filename
>   --- shows file not on client.

Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: I also looked into workspace to see if the file is present. Its not synced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run "p4 files //depot/filename" and you will see that it is a deleted file.

If an older version of the file were present on your client (i.e. "p4 have" said there was something there), "p4 sync" would remove it.  Since the file is already not present on your client, you are already "up to date".

Running "p4 sync -f" forces the issue and attempts to delete the local file even though the have table says nothing is there.  (If you'd added a brand new file in its place and hadn't done "p4 add" yet, that file is now lost forever -- be careful when using "p4 sync -f"!)

Comment: Yes, the file is deleted from depot. Now I understood the issue here. Thank you @sam-stafford for the answer.